# where in this code am I invoking the copy constructor?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

in an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256494/why-is-deleting-this-object-causing-problems) I have been informed that my problems lie to the call to a copy constructor in the code below. However, I just don't see where it's being invoked. Nowhere am I doing something like `agents[1] = agents[0];` although clearly I don't understand something. Where is this copying occurring and how can I change it so it's just making new objects each time?

I have been

```
int main()
{
    Level* level;
    std::vector<Agent> agents;

    level = new Level(agents);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) // this will be more than 1 in the future.
    {
        agents.push_back(Agent(100, *level, agents, level->Pickups(), D3DXCOLOR(1.0F, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1.0f)));
    }

    delete level;

}
```

Comment: I suppose that you use a pointer to Level only for an example on stackoverflow, and not in real code where an object would be more appropriate?

Comment: @TristramGräbener: If `Level` is really really huge, it might not only be heaped for StackOverflow (the site) but to prevent stack-overflows (the error).

Comment: It's rather difficult to have really huge objects (excepted using arrays, what i'd discourage in favor of vectors). And he dereferences level to pass it to the constructor of Agent, so I'm not convinced its size is a real problem (of course, it might be passed as reference... who knows)

Comment: I don't understand, what's the problem with creating a new level and using a pointer to refer to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have said, `push_back` will insert a copy into the vector.

If you have a compiler with some C++11 support it's possibly that you can avoid this copy by constructing the object directly into the vector. The new `emplace_back` function does this:

```
agents.emplace_back(100, *level, agents, level->Pickups(), D3DXCOLOR(1.0F, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1.0f));
```

In addition, if the compiler has C++11 support for move semantics, `push_back` will do a move operation instead of a copy operation if a move constructor is available for `Agent`, because you're passing it a temporary.

Comment: the missing `Agent` before the parameters is deliberate?

Comment: @SirYakalot Yes, `emplace_back` takes the constructor parameters and calls the constructor itself.

Comment: One question - push_back creates an object and copies it in to the vector, but how long does the original object persist for? until the loop ends? or every time it loops?

Comment: also I just changed my code to this, and I get "too many arguments in function call". It seems to want me to put `Agent` before the arguments.

Comment: @SirYakalot the original object lasts until the end of the statement. It goes away immediately after the function call. And it's not `push_back` that creates the original object, it's the `Agent(..)` part. `push_back` just copies that. Now, what compiler are you using? It may be that `emplace_back` is not supported by it yet.

Comment: I just checked, and if you're using Microsoft's compiler, `emplace_back` is not correctly supported (more here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4306581/46642).

Comment: visual studio 2010, it's OK i'm reading up about copy constructors to solve my other problem. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
agents.push_back(Agent(100, *level, agents, level->Pickups(), D3DXCOLOR(1.0F, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1.0f)));
```

This creates a temporary `Agent` object and a copy of it is taken an pushed in the `vector`.

Comment: how do I amend this to just create new ones for each slot?

Comment: What do you mean? If you want to avoid copying, you can use pointers, but then you'll have to worry about memory management.

Answer (score 0):

at the line below you are creating a temporary Agent and copying it into a new Agent that is created within the agents by passing the temporary Agent.

agents.push_back(Agent(100, *level, agents, level->Pickups(), D3DXCOLOR(1.0F, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1.0f)));

Answer (score 0):

Your `std::vector::push_back` has copy semantics. It must invoke `Agent::Agent(Agent const&)`.

You *cannot* use `std::vector` with something that does not have a meaningful copy constructor. You might have to resort to a vector of pointers (which have trivial copy constructors).

Comment: what exactly is `Agent::Agent(Agent const&)`?

Comment: @SirYakalot: `Agent::Agent(Agent const&)` is the prototype of the copy constructor of the `Agent` type.

Comment: so is my problem that I AM using it? or that I'm not? Sorry I don't quite understand.

Comment: @SirYakalot: I can only guess, because your question is a bit vague. I would assume that you asked because your compiler told you that there is no copy constructor. `std::vector` requires one (**it** uses it) and if you implemented at least one constructor but didn't explicitly implement the copy constructor, the default copy constructor was removed by C++, resulting in a type that lacks the ability to be copy constructed, hence lacks the ability to be stored in `std::vector`.

Comment: @bitmask: the copy constructor is not removed if you implement another constructor (the default constructor is, though).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Ah, darn. You're right -- you have to explicitly hide it if you don't want it. Sorry for the mix up.