# using a method declared pure virtual in derived classes

Tags: c++, oop, virtual, derived-class

I am working with a code and I saw something odd, a method of a class "MyClass" let's call it X() :

```
virtual void X() = 0;
```

So MyClass is an abstract class and in MyClass.cpp X() has a proper implementation...
In derived classes of MyClass, this method is called via MyClass::X();

I thought that `= 0` would invalidate its implementation... but it's not the case and it is, in fact, usable in derived classes.

Can you please tell what the compiler really do when he encounters `= 0` ?

Comment: Relevant: [Why does it make sense to give definition for a pure virtual function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918637/why-does-it-make-sense-to-give-definition-for-a-pure-virtual-function)

Comment: You can't instanciate MyClass because you tell X is not defined, and that it has to be implemented in child class (it's called an abstract class in lots of languages).

Comment: Your answer is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089083/pure-virtual-function-with-implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the standard (9.2 Class members [class.mem]):

> `= 0` is the `pure-specifier`

It tells that compiler that:

1. the class is *abstract*
2. the method will be defined *outside* the class definition
   (usually in a derived class)

### Example 1 (build fails)

If I understand your question correctly, you have something like that:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    virtual void X() = 0;
};

class MyDerivedClass : MyClass {
public:
    virtual void X();
};

void MyDerivedClass::X() { MyClass::X(); }

int main()
{
    MyDerivedClass mdc;
    mdc.X();

    return 0;    
}
```

If so, the build should fail with:

#### Error:

```
undefined reference to 'MyClass::X()'
```

### Example 2 (build succeeds)

However, even if the method `MyClass::X()` is declared as *pure virtual*,
you can provide a definition. The following would work. The class `MyClass`
is still *abstract*, but you can call the method `MyClass::X()`.

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
public:
    virtual void X() = 0; // pure virtual method
};

class MyDerivedClass : MyClass {
public:
    virtual void X();
};

void MyClass::X() {       // pure virtual method definition
    std::cout << "MyClass::X()" << std::endl;
}

void MyDerivedClass::X() {
    MyClass::X();
    std::cout << "MyDerivedClass::X()" << std::endl;
}  

int main()
{
    MyDerivedClass mdc;
    mdc.X();

    return 0;    
}
```

#### Output:

```
MyClass::X()
MyDerivedClass::X()
```

Answer (score 2):

The =0 thing tells the compiler two things:

1. A regular out-of-class function definition is not required (though allowed). If there is no such definition, and the function is actually called, this is a runtine error.
2. The class is abstract and cannot be instantiated, whether a definition from point 1 is present or not. Attempts to do so should be flagged as compile time errors. Derived classes that don't override the function are abstract too.

Answer (score 0):

You could not create instance of class with pure virtual methods, but in some cases you can call pure virtual methods, and it will be an [error](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/125749)

Comment: [Not necessarily](http://ideone.com/WPAdUw).

Comment: @n.m. if you provide realization of course it will work. But usually pure virtual methods have no

Comment: The question is about a pure virtual method that does have an implementation. Pure virtual destructors *must* have an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the compiler creates a vtable with NULL pointers for pure virtual methods.