# How do I ensure the destruction of a parent instance member?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider these two classes in C++11:

```
class A
{
    ArbitraryClass someInstance;
};

class B : public A
{

};
```

And consider I use `B` as such:

```
B *foo = new B;
delete foo;
```

As I understand, the implicit destructor of `A` will not be called here.

Is `someInstance` still destroyed under these circumstances, because it becomes "associated" as a member of `B`? Or do I need to declare a virtual destructor on `A` to automatically trigger the member's destruction?

Comment: "As I understand, the implicit destructor of A will not be called here." why do you think that?  Did you try it?  Without virtual destructors, the static variable type of the object will have its destructor called along with all parent types.  With a virtual destructor the dynamic object type will have its destructor called along with all its parent types.

Comment: Good books: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: I think you're confused. You question would make more sense (as a point of understanding, not confusion), if `someInstance` were a member of `B`, and `foo` was `A*`.

Comment: @xaxxon I misread the what [this answer was suggesting,](http://stackoverflow.com/a/677623/1429658) mixing up the `D` and `B` classes -- Thus my confusion, and thus the false statement. That clears everything up.

Comment: @WhozCraig Confused and apparently dyslexic. :')

Comment: @Litty it happens. I think you were shooting for the difference betwee [**this**](http://ideone.com/jKp1DC), and [**that**](http://ideone.com/4PF1tu).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a virtual destructor in a `delete` expression's statically known class (in your case `B`) if that class is different from the most derived class of the object (in your case also `B`). In your case those classes are the same, so you don't need a virtual destructor: everything's destroyed properly. But if you had made the pointer type `A*`, then you'd need a virtual destructor in `A` to avoid Undefined Behavior (nasal daemons and such).

Answer (score 4):

> How do I ensure ...

Mostly by doing nothing.

> As I understand, the implicit destructor of A will not be called here.

Wrong.

> Is `someInstance` still destroyed under these circumstances

Yes.

> because it becomes "associated" as a member of B?

Because it is a member of A, and A is destroyed.

> Or do I need to declare a virtual destructor on A to automatically trigger the member's destruction?

Not in the case of the code you posted, but if (as is likely) you will be using polymorphism by deleting pointers to A that could be B or other subclasses of A you should give A a virtual destructor.