# What order are destructors called and member variables destroyed in C++ using inhertitance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, visual-studio-2008, destructor

Very similar question as these, except not exactly: [What is the order in which the destructors and the constructors are called in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654428/what-is-the-order-in-which-the-destructors-and-the-constructors-are-called-in-c)
[Order of member constructor and destructor calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254263/order-of-member-constructor-and-destructor-calls)

I want to know: are the member variables of the derived class destroyed before or after the destructor of the base class is called?

This is in C++ using Visual Studio 2008.  Thanks.

Comment: The members are destroyed after the destructor is run (since the destructor is allowed to access them, and most of the time does in order to free resources, etc.)

Comment: Worth noting that destructors *always* run in the opposite order as constructors, even when the latter is unspecified (e.g. global objects). So you only have to remember one or the other. At least, I believe this is true and would be interested to see a counter-example...

Comment: @Nemo: There is one case which doesn't fit (and only one): Unloading a dynamically loaded shared object (.so / .dll / ...). Still, that's outside the purview of the standard.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Thanks. Only "sort-of" counts as an exception, IMO, but worth knowing.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

constructor: first base, then derived

destruction:

- ~derived
- ~member derived
- ~base
- ~member base

code:

```
class member {
    string s;

public:
    member(string s) {
        this-> s = s;
    }

    ~member() {
        cout << "~member " << s << endl;
    }
};

class base {
    member m;
public:
    base() : m("base"){
    }

    ~base() {
        cout << "~base" << endl;
    }
};

class derived : base{
     member m2;
public:

    derived() :m2("derived") {    }

    ~derived() {
        cout << "~derived" << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    derived s;

    return 0;
}
```

#### References & virtual destructor

When you plan to dynamically allocate (i.e. when you use the keywords `new` & `delete`) a derived object, then **always** have a `virtual` or a `protected` destructor on your base. Dynamically deleting the object on the base class reference would otherwise lead to **memory leaks** in the example below:

```
class base {
    member m;
public:
    base() : m("base"){
    }

    /* correct behaviour is when you add **virtual** in front of the signature */
    ~base() {
        cout << "~base" << endl;
    }
};

class derived : public base{
     member m2;
    char* longArray;
public:

    derived() :m2("derived") {
        longArray = new char[1000];
    }


    ~derived() {
        delete[] longArray; // never called
        cout << "~derived" << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    base *s = new derived; // mind the downcast to **base**

    delete s; /* only the non-virtual destructor on the base and its members is called. 
               No destructor on derived or its members is called.
               What happens to the memory allocated by derived?
               **longArray** is leaked forever. 
               Even without **longArray**, it most probably **leaks** memory, as C++ doesn't define its behaviour 
               */
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

- ~base
- ~member base

Only base data is cleaned up, and `longArray` **leaks**.

Comment: You might want to add virtuals into the picture. As-is, your overview is simply wrong.

Comment: Well, you need to add virtual bases, and study up on the order.

Answer (score 12):

Here's what the standard says... (C++11, 12.4/8)

> After executing the body of the destructor and destroying any automatic objects allocated within the body, a
>   destructor for class `X` calls the destructors for `X`’s direct non-variant non-static data members, the destructors
>   for `X`’s direct base classes and, if `X` is the type of the most derived class (12.6.2), its destructor calls the
>   destructors for `X`’s virtual base classes. All destructors are called as if they were referenced with a qualified
>   name, that is, ignoring any possible virtual overriding destructors in more derived classes. Bases and
>   members are destroyed in the reverse order of the completion of their constructor (see 12.6.2). A return
>   statement (6.6.3) in a destructor might not directly return to the caller; before transferring control to the
>   caller, the destructors for the members and bases are called. Destructors for elements of an array are called
>   in reverse order of their construction (see 12.6).

Note that this order is indeed the reverse of the order given in 12.6.2/10 in C++11. You can't tell what the order of destruction of virtual bases is from looking at 12.4/8 alone, but you can infer it from 12.6.2/10, which specifies that initialization of virtual bases occurs in depth-first search left-to-right order. (Thus, destruction of virtual bases occurs in the reverse of that order.)

Anyway, you have your answer. Non-static members are destroyed first, then base classes. But a base class's members will be destroyed before the *next* base class's destructor starts. It really is exactly like depth-first search.

Comment: Doesn't your quote say non-static members are destroyed *before* base classes?

Comment: @Nemo my bad, mistyped

Comment: I am pretty sure destructors run in the opposite order as constructors, always.

Comment: @Nemo I'm pretty sure that's the case for the relative order of subobjects of classes, anyway. I'm not entirely sure whether it's true in general.

Comment: @Deduplicator Sorry, don't get you. What second sentence-part?

Comment: @Deduplicator I'm not sure what you mean, but I rewrote my answer slightly to make it more clear.

Comment: @ `Non-static members are destroyed first, then base classes.` because `static members` will not destroyed by destructor as they part of class not the object, right ?

Comment: @AbhishekMane correct. Static members are destroyed when the program terminates normally.

Comment: @BrianBi https://stackoverflow.com/q/67772282/11862989 can you answer this question please .