# How do I put a thread in a C++ smart pointer?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14

I want to create a C++ class with a thread doing some work once a minute.

First, may I define a thread as a variable member?

```
class my_class
{
public:
    my_class()
        : my_thread_(task, this)
    {
    }

    ~my_class()
    {
        done_ = true;
    }

    void run()
    {
        while(!done_)
        {
            ...do work in the thread...
        }
    }

private:
    static task(my_class * ptr)
    {
        ptr->run();
    }

    std::thread          my_thread_;
    std::atomic<bool>    done_ = false;
};
```

Second, may I instead use a smart pointer with the thread in it?

```
class my_class
{
public:
    ~my_class()
    {
        done_ = true;
    }

    void init()
    {
        my_thread_.reset(new std::thread(task, this));
    }

    void run()
    {
        while(!done_)
        {
            ...do work in the thread...
        }
    }

private:
    static task(my_class * ptr)
    {
        ptr->run();
    }

    std::unique_ptr<std::thread>    my_thread_;
    std::atomic<bool>               done_ = false;
};
```

It seems to me that I need to join with the child thread before it can be destroyed, but I am wondering whether the destructor of std::thread knows to do that safely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread),

> A thread object does not have an associated thread (and is safe to
>   destroy) after
>
> - it was default-constructed
> - it was moved from
> - join() has been called
> - detach() has been called

So if you define the thread as a member variable and write your destructor like this:

```
~my_class()
{
    done_ = true;
    my_thread_.join();
}
```

everything is fine, because it is guaranteed by the standard that the `std::thread` destructor will be called only after the `my_class` destructor, [see this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28356069/what-order-are-destructors-called-and-member-variables-destroyed-in-c-using-in).

Comment: I actually missed that list in the reference... It also means that std::thread is not exception safe!

Answer (score 5):

You can put `std::thread`s where ever you want, they are not special. Destroying thread handles is problematic. You can implicitly detach, implicitly kill or implicitly join and every option is bad. `std::~thread` (usually) [just kills the whole program](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread). To prevent that [`join`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) or [`detach`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) it.
Since you seem to want to implicitly join you may want to use [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) (probably with the [`std::launch::async` policy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/launch)) to launch your threads. It returns an [`std::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) who's destructor implicitly joins.

Comment: Only I want my process to always be running in the background and `std::async`, from what I understand, is not 100% guaranteed to create a trhead to run the task. It could do it in the front thread. But I really need to separate tasks running in parallel.

Comment: @AlexisWilke That's why I commented about the `std::launch::async` policy which forces `std::async` to create a thread. If you don't care about synchronization and just want a thread running use `std::thread` and call `.detach()` on it.

Answer (score 4):

it's possible to create `std::unique_ptr<std::thread>`. It will call std::thread destructor, when scope of unique_ptr will end. Remember that calling std::thread destructor is not terminating running thready gently, but by `std::terminate`. To end std::thread normally, you have to run `.join()` on std::thread object.